# SolrCloud - Out of Memory

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Were using SolrCloud 4.10.3 on the Cloudera Platform with a 3 node solr cluster with 2 collections of 3 shards each.
Collection 1: approx size: 15.3 GB Collection 2: size: 1.2GB

Our heap size is 8GB and off heap is 15GB. We have a realtime feed into solr for one of our collections (the other is pretty static). We are constantly getting an out of memory error.

Can anyone help us as to the reason? Should be we having additional shards to spread the load? Or do we need to keep giving more off heap memory? All the cloudera heap graphs show that we are find for heap space (we rarely go above 6.5GB) and GC pauses are not an issue.

Thanks

Comment: Could it be that your error is an"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : unable to create new native Thread"? If so, then the problem is not memory, but the number of "max user processes" (if you are using Linux). In that case, simply raise the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The best approach should be to upgrade the solr cloud to version
>   6.2.1.

it also depends on the node architecture if the node is of 32 bit arch. then heap size more than 2gb wont work if the node is of 64 bit arch you can allocate more heap size but can generate gc overhead error.

so better to update solr and add more shards and replicas to avoid the error.